# Why do Ashkenazi Orthodox Jews Chant With Reform Trope?

Tags: history, trop-cantillation

From what I've been able to gather the most popular/standard/traditional te'amim melodies were collected, blended, and then published by Abrahim Binder, a reform Jew.
Source: http://www.milkenarchive.org/artists/view/abraham-binder/

It seems to me that the Orthodox movement makes many declarations about how the Reform movement has broken away or is destroying tradition. And so the idea that the te'amim system would be based on the works of the Reform movement would be really hypocritical. So why use the system?

Comment: I think the article you included speaks for itself- Binder essentially codified differing Ashkenazi tropes, creating a sort of "Standard Ashkenazi" trope that could be used by all.

Comment: The claim that the trop used by Orthodox Jews changed to match something designed by a Reform Jew needs better substantiation in the question.

Comment: @Josh K But doesn't that go against the Orthodox ethos? A guy coming in and mishmashing isn't really tradition, is it?

Comment: Every region and sub-region of Europe had its own cantillation, @Aaron, there had to be some kind of standardization

Comment: @Josh K why would there need to be?

Comment: In Europe, there were local tropes and minhagim that outsiders had to adjust to if the moved into town. In the US, people were a mishmash of Jewish communitites from all over, and standardization was needed to get everyone on the same page, as it were. This standardization is what gave rise to American Reform Judaisim, incidentally, as well as the Orthodox and Conservative responses to it

Comment: The same standardization led to artscroll nusach ashkenaz instead of all the variants, @JoshK . It's a natural part of minhagim when communities move. Trutt is there still is some subtle variation out there among different baalei kriya

Comment: Incorporating evidence that the tune used by Orthodox folks changed to Binder's would drastically imrove your post. Maybe they still use what they did before he came along? (Also, explaining better what's wrong with using the product of a Reform guy's labor would improve your post.)

Comment: Wouldn't the same question be applicable to why Jews use Bomberg's layout?

Comment: You act as if no one uses "unique" Ashkenazi trop systems anymore. Although the "standard" system is most common in American Ashkenazi synagogues, there are still many Ashkenazi communities out there using more traditional systems. For example, I can think of one example - Lubavitch has its own trop method, which I'm sure is also used by other communities of Russian origin (although I'm not sure).

Comment: @ezra Yekkes have their own tune, and they are Ashkenazi. The Shamash / Ba'al Koreh in my "youngster" shul in Washington Heights used a "non-familiar" tune which, years later, I discovered was the Chaba"d tune. In hindsight, I'm not sure why, as neither he nor the shul were Chaba"d. He must have learned it himself at some point.

Answer (score 0):

The article only refers to melodies to adon olam and other songs, not the cantillation system used in the Torah. And if he popularized some songs that he collected, that does not make him the composer.